# Android emulator not showing the app- it only shows the skin

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I started to develop android apps a few days ago, but I'm stuck with this problem.

I'm using Eclipse with ADT and have created the simple `Hello World` or any of the other sample applications, and when I run the project, Eclipse launches the Android emulator but it shows only the skin, with the screen saying "ANDROID" and nothing else, it's unresponsive to anything I do in the code.

It happens targeting both 2.2 and 1.5 versions, why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Comment: For me it loads in 5 minutes, so you might have to wait 5-10 minutes to start.

Comment: i just came across this because i had the same problem - if you leave it open, you will see your app on the app screen on the emulator and you can just run it from there

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The emulator will show "ANDROID" when it's loading. You will have to give it a minuto for it to start. If it does not start it could be cause for several reasons: for instance, if your computer don't have enough resources to run the emulator, or if there are internal problems with the SDK, etc. Try to run the emulator from the SDK folder and see if it works; if not, the problem could be your computer.

Comment: .. and check the logfile via "adb shell logcat" from command line to check if there are any errors. Also check the Output console tab in Eclipse/DDMS if it gives an error.

Answer (score 2):

Cristian's right - the "ANDROID" display is the loading screen. Give it a minute or two - if the main screen does not appear then, there may be some sort of problem. If so, you may also want to check that you created the emulator properly (a.k.a. for the version you are using, etc).

If the main screen does eventually show, then the loading process is simply slow. To deal with this during development, I would suggest leaving the emulator open when you compile and run your application code. The old version of the application will be replaced by the new one, and the app will automatically restart.

Comment: thanks tlayton. i will try your suggestion and keep the emulator open, when i return home tonight.